# String to Integer Android

Tags: android

I`ve problem with converting String to Integer.

```
   public SharedPreferences abc;
   abc = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Trening",0);



   Integer i = Integer.parseInt(abc.getString("T1",null).toString());
```

The Error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I learn to program for 3 days and hope you can help me and explain how to fix it, so I can learn.

Sorry for my english. :)

Comment: You can not convert null to integer. What are you storeing in your sharedpreferences?

Comment: @zkminusck What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `null` as second argument in `abc.getString("T1", null)`, actualy you are saying:
if "T1" value is not set, return `null` as default.
So you have `parsInt(null)` and it causes NullPointerExceprion. 
You can replace 
`abc.getString("T1", null)` with
 `abc.getString("T1", "0")`

It will returns **string** "0" as default value of "T1" (if "T1" is null). So you have `parsInt("0")` that it works proprely.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I understood what you wrote and it helped me, but the same erros occured

Comment: Are you in an activity or non-activity class??

Comment: It seems your abc is null. Log it and tell me result. Also you can remove "getApplicationContext()"

Comment: The mistace can be: I`ve public SharedPreferences abc; and
   abc = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Trening",0); in one class and Integer i = Integer.parseInt(abc.getString("T1",null).toString());  in other class. The second class extends the first class but not AppCompatActivity. Am I right ?

Comment: @GreenFace  post more code so i can find that what is your activities structure. However `abc` is null and its because you are instantiating it in a class and using it in another.

Answer (score 1):

If `abc.getString("T1", null)` returns `null` (this will happen if there is no Key-Value-Pair with the key "T1" in your SharedPreferences) then you try to get the String of `null`. This causes the NullPointerException. You should define another defaultValue which can be converted into a String.

Apart from that, you can leave `toString()` out because `getString()` returns a String:

```
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(abc.getString("T1", "-1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem basically is that the variable **abc** is null, therefore the **getSharedPreferences** call fails to retrieve a valid reference.